# Google reCAPTCHA V2 - trigger harder version for testing?

Tags: testing, captcha, bots, recaptcha

Is there some trick that will make Google suspicious of me?

For various reasons, we want to (for testing) trigger the harder version (e.g. click all the images that show food) instead of just the "I am not a robot" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You might just use [iMacros](https://webscraping.pro/data-extraction-using-imacros-plugin-for-ie/) code. It makes google to suspect bot visiting and thus put forth the image puzzle.

```
VERSION BUILD=9052613
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
' you need to insert get other url where ReCaptcha is located.
URL GOTO=http://... 
' we generate random number to make robot wait some seconds (1-6 seconds)
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*5 + 1); randomNumber;")
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
FRAME F=1 TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:recaptcha-anchor
```

Comment: Actually Google reCaptcha is sensitive to cookie. So if you open your browser in an incognito mode (Chorme) or private window (FF)  Google will always trigger harder version.